# how to redirect anyone, accessing a specific folder to receive 404 error with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect people, that try to access a specific folder on web to receive 404
Example: if anyone wants to access `www.mysite/myfolder/` I wish that person to receive 404 error
What I have tried by now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/node/$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RedirectMatch 301 www.yoursite/node/


RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^//node/123 /node/999 /node/128173/(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

None of those really worked-received 500 error
Also tried to simply redirect everything to a non-existent site, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /node/*.*   http://www.your imaginary site/to-new-url
```

Yet, still received 500
Can anyone please help?

Comment: What does your Apache error logs say when you visit? Additionally if you are trying to create a custom 404 page you would use `ErrorDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Why not deny access to /node/ folder?

```
<Directory /node/>
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

or modify your rewrites in .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^node/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/errors/404.php [R=301,L]
```

But it's not good practice, 404 page should return HTTP 404 status not HTTP 301 as redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all and thank you for answering
my 500 error was apparently due to not specifying https in the redirect form
After that everything worked